# If the 1st $4$ glasses drawn are nondefective, what is the probability of finding $2$ defective glasses in next $6$ draws?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

> Out of $20$ glasses, $2$ are defective. If the first $4$ glasses drawn are nondefective, what is the probability of finding $2$ defective glasses in next $6$ draws?

Here $18$ are nondefective and $2$ are defective.

I tried doing $$\frac{\dfrac{18!}{4!14!} \cdot \dfrac{6!}{2!4!}}{ \dfrac{20!}{2!18!}}$$

But I seem to be doing something wrong since I am considering $2$ draws out of a sample of $20$ in the lower part of the calculation and above I am drawing actually $6$. Can any one please help here in choosing the probability of finding $2$ defective glasses out of $6$ chances after finding $4$ nondefective glasses in the first $4$ draws?

Comment: Four non-defective glasses have been drawn, so you should only consider the 16 remaining glasses.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: @DanielMathias, hint worked , thankyou

Comment: @Shariq this is great that you send back comments and appreciate comments by others! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found the right answer as $$\frac{\dfrac{6!}{2!4!}}{\dfrac{16!}{2!14!}}$$

Thanks Daniel. The hint given by you helped.

This because when 1st $4$ samples are chosen as nondefective, then the sample size for finding the $2$ defective glasses has become $16$ instead of $20$, and then it is all about finding $2$ defectives out of first $6$ samples.

Comment: This should be an edit to the question.

Comment: Are you trying to find the probability that at least one defective glass is selected in the next six draws or that both defective glasses are selected in the next six draws?

Comment: 2 defective glass in next 6 @N.F.Taussig

Comment: I have edited the original question accordingly.  Your solution makes sense.  By the way, you can obtain $\binom{n}{k}$ by typing `$\binom{n}{k}$`.